# Setting custom $this->request->data without breaking rest of form?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an add() view for Lessons - in it I have a form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Lesson'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Lesson'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('course_id', array('selected' => $this->request->data['named']['belongsToCourse']));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

It seems that when I set `$this->request->data['named']['belongsToCourse']` in the controller, it somehow made it so that I am not saving the `$this->Form->input('name');`

How do I set the `course_id` without breaking the `$this->request->data` which should include the new lesson's name?

Here's the error I get when trying to save. Because it thinks I'm saving a duplicate name `''`:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'
```

Here is the action add():

```
public function add() {
        $this->request->data = $this->request->params;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $courseID = $this->request->data['named']['belongsToCourse'];
            $this->Lesson->create();
            if ($this->Lesson->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The lesson has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'courses', 'action' => 'view', $courseID));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The lesson could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        //debug(func_get_args());
        $courses = $this->Lesson->Course->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('courses'));

        //$this->Form->input('course_id') = $belongsToCourse;
}
```

Comment: First, is the course_id of the lessons table set as unique in your db? Second, show the action for the view with the form?

Comment: @Nunser course_id does not seem to be set to unique. the action for the view with the form is added to the question.

Comment: What you are doing there is highly unconventional. You should not be juggling around with request data like that. Stick to the conventions and what the book/tutorial teaches you. Also you should not use "selected" for default values. It breaks the form. See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/).

Comment: @mark sorry I'm relatively new to cakephp. Do you mean passing the params through the model instead? Thanks for the update. I'll look in there.

Comment: You can save it using `Form::hidden()`and `value`  attribute